# How do I make my bot not mention users when it responds?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get my bot to reply to a specific command, but I don't want him to mention the user who uses the command when he replies with his pre-loaded response. Could anyone help?

I think it may be due to the code 'msg.reply' but I'm not sure how to edit it to ensure that he doesn't mention the user.

Thanks!

```
 client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '!events') {
      msg.reply(`Birthday party - September 14th
Christening - October 18th
Halloween - October 31st`);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

2021 update: With the new reply feature, it is possible to avoid mentioning ("pinging") the users whose message you are replying to. You just have to set the `allowedMentions` for `repliedUser` to `false`:

```
reaction.message.reply({
    content: 'Your message here',
    allowedMentions: {
        repliedUser: false
    }
} as ReplyMessageOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing `message.reply` do `message.channel.send`

```
client.on('message', msg => { 
    if (msg.content === '!events') {
        msg.channel.send('Birthday party - September 14th Christening - October 18th Halloween - October 31st'); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: This answer was provided before discord's "reply" feature was added. The Discord.js library used to prepend a mention to any string given to the TextMessage#reply method. This was the correct answer at the time and what OP was asking for. The answer is now outdated because the question itself is outdated.